# What platform should educational games target?

Tags: ios, educational-games

Should educational games target the PC or mobile market? My professional development experience has been with the PC, but I'm wondering if mobile (iOS, Android, etc.) has a better market for educational games (elementary/middle). Has anyone been in this market and have a good idea?

[This article](http://venturebeat.com/2013/08/16/with-a-mobile-boom-learning-games-are-a-1-5b-market-headed-toward-2-3b-by-2017-exclusive/) says

> “Mobile educational games are now outselling PC educational games,” he said. “And the entrepreneurs are incredibly passionate about what they are doing. What we find interesting is the interest among investors in mobile.”

Comment: What's "a good market"? Safe? Profitable? Easy? Pick 2. :)

Comment: Profitable and good user base, for the most part.

Comment: I think there is another important variable and that is, what is the budget for the game? I think low budget educational games prosper in the mobile market and would be less likely to receive attention on the PC market. This is an observation I do not wish to prove.

Answer (score 2):

Most kids don't download educational games on their phones, so I feel that it would be best to make a Windows program for schools. All the schools I've ever been in use Windows, but it differs.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I think you should go for the mobile market. Younger and younger ages have more access to mobile technologies as they become more popular, and they avoid a lot of hassle to get started to play the game. For example, a child that wants to play a game on the computer usually needs an adult to log them in, find the shortcut or exe, and usually requires a higher level of knowledge to play (mouse, keyboard takes more brain power than jabbing a screen). With a mobile app, they pick up the device and jab the picture of the game they want to play. The mobile platform has many other intuitive controls that apply to children such as rotation and tilting, and easier access to things like a microphone which could be used for voice.

Answer (score 1):

As a parent, I'd buy worthwhile educational games for my daughter on my tablet and phone. It depends on the target age group, but a touch screen is a lot more intuitive to a young child than a mouse.

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable answer here is **both**.

In my (limited, ~1 year) experience in this space, the areas that do well are:

1) Mobile native app

or

2) Responsive web-based game that looks and feels great on many devices (from PCs down to phones).

Schools are moving more and more towards having tablets in class to supplement lessons so (1) would target that area.

Having a game that is accessible regardless of platform (2) is obviously the largest net you can cast. With that comes its own set of challenges however (testing multiple devices, security for the user, etc).

Making a fun game is hard, making a fun game that also achieves educational goals is even harder. Good luck!